# Value cannot be null. ASP.NET MVC Dropdown List Fails on Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET's Register view and added a dropdown list to hold category as seen below:
[image: Modified Registration Form]

This is the code for my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountCategory, "Account Type", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountCategory, new SelectList(Model.AccountCategories, "Id", "Category"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

My ViewModel bound to the categories is:

```
[Required]
    public int AccountCategory { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AccountCategory> AccountCategories { get; set; }
```

And my I modified the Register controller to accomodate the category field as such:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        var category = _context.Categories.Single(c => c.Id == model.AccountCategory);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                CategoryId = category.Id,
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                OtherName = model.OtherName,
                LastName = model.LastName
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

But when I click the submit button, I get this error:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: items

Source Error:

```
Line 15:     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountCategory, "Account Type", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
Line 16:     <div class="col-md-10">
Line 17:         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountCategory, new SelectList(Model.AccountCategories, "Id", "Category"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
Line 18:     </div>
Line 19: </div>
```

Any assistancce will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bound an `int` property and pass it directly as `SelectList`. The `AccountCategories` model should look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AccountCategories { get; set; }
```

And this is how to pass the drop down list items properly to `DropDownListFor`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountCategory, Model.AccountCategories, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

NB: The `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instance should have filled with `Id` & `Category` property values, such like `new SelectListItem() { Text = Category, Value = Id }`.

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountCategory, Model.AccountCategories, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

To

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountCategory,Model.AccountCategories.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Category}) , "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I have corrected changed this line, I used { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Category} because Value expects a string. But I still got an error: "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source"

Comment: are you sending any data into  Model.AccountCategories? and may be issue with this list only. check whether it contains any null values.